# db issues when dockerizing Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize an existing rails application. But it's running into an error when trying to invoke `rake db:create`.

Here is the error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, 
"database"=>"app_development", "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"postgres"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app

# COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
# RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: app_development
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  db_data:
```

database.yml

```
...
development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development
  # url: postgres://...
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried everything online and still no luck. Any catches? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for your database url?  Are you referencing the container by name?

I've gotten this to work in a number of projects, but I usually expose the ports for the database (5432 for postgres) and use `localhost` to bind the two together.  I'm sure you could just use container names though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to communicate over TCP/IP rather than a socket, so you should be able to sort this using the host setting in your database.yml file

```
...
development:
<<: *default
username: postgres
database: postgres
host: 127.0.0.1
```